# Incorrect syntax near 'p'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

**Error:**

```
*Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'
Incorrect syntax near 'p'.
/TEST/order.asp, line 105*
```

**Line 105:**

```
*Set rs = conn.Execute("INSERT INTO orders (OrderNumber,Items,DateT,Valuex,Name,Address,Email,Instructions,Terms,CountryFlag,Newsletter) VALUES  ('"&OrderNumber&"','"&Items&"','"&DateT&"','"&Valuex&"','"&Name&"','"&Address&"','"&Email&"','"&Instructions&"','"&Terms&"','"&CountryFlag&"','"&Newsletter&"')")*
```

This works perfectly fine on our current website but not on the reskinned version. I'm assuming it's down to an error in a previous page where the session variables must be messed up?

Comment: You might have `'` in one of those value. You want to use parameterized query.

Comment: Please go and read about sql injection as this is dangerously open to it, it will likely also fix the problem.

Comment: Since you're not controlling your SQL query, your syntax error could be anywhere.  Use query parameters instead of this dynamic string concatenation, that way you actually control the syntax of the query.  And, as an added bonus, you'd stop treating user input as *executable code*.

Comment: Good feedback and advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easiest if you converted it to a stored procedure.

However for your current situation its probably easier to create a command object and parse the values as parameters.

```
        Dim sqlstring As String = "INSERT INTO orders (OrderNumber, Items, DateT, Valuex, Name, Address, Email, Instructions, Terms, CountryFlag, Newsletter) " _
    + "VALUES('@OrderNumber', '@Items', '@DateT', '@Valuex', '@Name', '@Address', '@Email', '@Instructions', @Terms', '@CountryFlag', '@Newsletter')"

    Dim comm As New SqlCommand(sqlstring, conn)
    comm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@OrderNumber", OrderNumber))
    comm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Items", Items))
    comm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DateT", DateT))
    comm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Valuex", Valuex))
    comm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Name", Name))
    comm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Address", Address))
    comm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Email", Email))
    comm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Instructions", Instructions))
    comm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Terms", Terms))
    comm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CountryFlag", CountryFlag))
    comm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Newsletter", Newsletter))

    conn.Execute()
```

Comment: Please explain why this would be "easiest" ass a stored procedure? The code you have added is also not quite right too.

Comment: Re-look at the Query you had put all parameter in `''`